# Checkbox so user can decide whether image should be displayed or not

Tags: media

I would like to add a checkbox yes / no whether the image field should be displayed or not in a node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mh, there are several ways.

One of this is to add a boolean field to the content type. 
Then you can create a template for the node, or the field, and display it only if the value of the boolean field is "on".

What do you think?

Comment: sounds good to me.